# Android Multiple Shape Drawables In LinearLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-drawable

Okay, so all I am trying to do is set four circles up in a linear layout. The problem is the circles show up as ovals. I have tried not setting width and height in the circle.xml files, I have tried setting width of the circles in the view to 0dp, wrap_content and 50dp to match the height, still, ovals. I have tried not setting the weightSum in the layout with the same result, it's like it doesn't need to be there.

LinearLayout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/xlarge_padding"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/xlarge_padding"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="4">
```

circle_blue.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">
<size
    android:width="50dp"
    android:height="50dp" />
<solid android:color="@color/fc_blue"/>
```

I am calling the circles with Views that have the width set to 0dp and the height to 50dp, and the layout_weight to 1 with the background set to circle_xxx.xml.

Should I just ditch the weight settings and use padding to space them apart?

Here is a screenshot of how they look on device

https://www.dropbox.com/s/afh8d8m3jrbhrzf/Screenshot_2015-09-27-06-35-07.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the effect of using **weights**.
I guessed that, because you used the (useless) `weightSum` attribute in the LinearLayout.

Now, weights actually modify the children Views dimensions, which are no more 50dp in width, while they maintain 50dp in height.

This is why you get **ovals**, instead of circles.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I removed all the weight attributes and miraculously they were spaced evenly in the layout anyway. :)